# I had An unexpected error when deploy Nuxt 3 in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzO-KVMx7lo) for deploy my nuxt 3 project. This is how my firebase.json look like:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": ".output/server",
      "runtime": "nodejs16"
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".output/public",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "server"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

i also changed my nuxt.config.ts as follow:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    preset: 'firebase'
  },
.....
```

then i run this script in package.json (i modified from tutorial, based my own requirement).

`"deploy-fb": "cd .output/server && rm -rf node_modules && npm i && cd .. && firebase deploy",`

But sadly, i got error

[image: error]

trace Error in `firebase-debug.log` like so,

```
[debug] [2024-03-06T17:37:51.732Z] Building nodejs source
[info] i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy 
[debug] [2024-03-06T17:37:51.734Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[debug] [2024-03-06T17:37:51.743Z] Found firebase-functions binary at '/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/.output/server/node_modules/.bin/firebase-functions'
[info] Serving at port 8566

[debug] [2024-03-06T17:37:53.072Z] Got response from /__/functions.yaml {"endpoints":{"server":{"platform":"gcfv1","availableMemoryMb":null,"timeoutSeconds":null,"minInstances":null,"maxInstances":null,"ingressSettings":null,"serviceAccountEmail":null,"vpc":null,"region":[null],"httpsTrigger":{},"entryPoint":"server"}},"specVersion":"v1alpha1","requiredAPIs":[]}
[debug] [2024-03-06T17:37:58.266Z] TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match')
    at resolveString (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/params.js:31:27)
    at /Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/params.js:47:36
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveList (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/params.js:47:21)
    at toBackend (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/build.js:181:30)
    at Object.resolveBackend (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/build.js:74:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async prepare (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/prepare.js:69:62)
    at async chain (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:38:9)
    at async deploy (/Users/julapps/web/gundu-web/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:95:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Please someone help me

Comment: it basically states that the `functions.yaml` doesn't exist. So you will need to create one I think

Comment: @AdamBasha thanks for responding, could you give me suggestion of values in functions.yaml. I don't see it part of tutorial so am very new about this and need help

Comment: This can help you with the `functions.yaml` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121723/what-is-functions-yaml

Comment: that link still doesn't give me result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent for almost three days, i found the solution of my case. This is because it has something was happened with the nitro https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14439 After i checked carefully at debug.log file in folder `.output/server` there was a dependency problem (in my case, there problem similarly like this https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3711) and it is blocking the deployment process. So, what i did is deleting `node_modules` folder in `.output/server` then run `npm install` in there. If this process is success then execute deployment. Everything going well after that